# My Windows server is running OOM, this prevents me to remote desktop. How can I remotely reboot it?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-10

I'm using a Windows 10 machine as a server. There is an application running on my server that leaks memory. This caused my server to run out of memory to the extent that I can't even connect to it using the remote desktop connection. SSH is also disabled on that machine. What is the best way to remotely reboot my server? I would need a lighter weight way than remote desktop to connect to the server, so that can work with the limited memory left.

Comment: Windows 10 is not a server OS, weird things like that can occur if you try to use a desktop OS as a server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi and welcome to ServerFault.

The easiest way of rebooting your server would be to use its [out-of-band management solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management#Implementation), whatever it might be - iDRAC, ILO, IPMI, or other kind of [BMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface#Baseboard_management_controller).

Lacking that, and being unable to connect via RDP, I don't see a way of doing it remotely. I suggest getting there and using the physical console or, as ultima ratio, pulling the power cable.

Once you regain access, have a look at [WinRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Management).

Furthermore, consider investing in actual server hardware and operating system.